Weird behaviour in HTML page with event listener actions not responding
I'm having a weird behaivour in a HTML page and I have no clue what's happening and even how to fix it. So, I have this HTML page which is dinamycally built using thymeleaf framework. Everything is working fine and as expected. For this page, I have a table (once again, dinamically built) with some columns (tr's and td's) and at the end of each TD I put a couple of "buttons" to edit and remove the selected item (in this case, the whole tr). Here's the table:
<!-- Option List table -->
<div id="tableBlock" style="display: block;">
    <hr width="40%" style="margin-left: 0;"/>
    <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Options List</h3>
    <table id="tableOptionList" class="stripped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Option Text</th>
                <th>Is right option?</th>
                <th>
                    <span>
                        <i id="trashAllItems" class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Removes al Option List items"></i>
                    </span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
            <tr th:id="'trItem-' + ${iter.count}" th:each="item, iter : ${iteratorObject.options}">
                <td th:id="'tdIndex-' + ${iter.count}" width="10%">[[${iter.count}]]</td>
                <td th:id="'optionTextFor_' + ${item.id}" class="optionTextClass" 
                        width="60%" th:utext="${item.optionText}"></td>
                <td class="rightOptionClass" width="20%">
                    <input th:id="'chk_' + ${item.id}" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" th:checked="${item.rightOption}" disabled />
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <span>
                        <i th:id="'editItem-' + ${iter.count} + '-id-' + ${item.id}" class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
                        <i th:id="'trashItem-' + ${iter.count} + '-id-' + ${item.id}" class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

Which produces following HTML extract:
<!-- Option List table -->
<div id="tableBlock" style="display:block;">
    <hr width="40%" style="margin-left: 0;">
    <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Options List</h3>
    <table id="tableOptionList" class="stripped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Option Text</th>
                <th>Is right option?</th>
                <th>
                    <span>
                        <i id="trashAllItems" class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Removes al Option List items"></i>
                    </span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="trItem-1">
                <td id="tdIndex-1" width="10%">1</td>
                <td id="optionTextFor_9" class="optionTextClass" width="60%">Some text.</td>
                <td class="rightOptionClass" width="20%">
                    <input id="chk_9" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" disabled="">
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <span>
                        <i id="editItem-1-id-9" class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
                        <i id="trashItem-1-id-9" class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

When the page get rendered, everithing work fine, I'm able to edit items, remove items, etc. The problem became when I programatically add a new item to the table with exactly the same structure which produces a plain html text like this:
<tr id="trItem-4"><td id="tdIndex-4" width="10%">4</td><td id="optionTextFor_4" class=" optionTextClass" width="60%">Some other text here</td><td class="rigthOptionClass" width="20%"><input id="chk_4" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" disabled=""></td><td width="10%"><span><i id="editItem-4-id-24" class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; <i id="trashItem-4-id-24" class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></td></tr>

The thing is, for each  element dinamically build I have a jQuery event listener to handle the actions properly; and it works! But once I insert a new row it's when the weird behaivour happens: the new  elements doesn't respond the the event I'm listening for (whereas the original ones still does).
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa-trash-o').click(function(){
        // Works fine with dinamically built elements but does not work with
        // programatically inserted elements.
    });

    $('.fa-pencil-square').click(function(){
    });

    $("i[id^=editItem]").click(function(){
        console.log("Nothing to do here");
    });
    
    $("i[id^=trashItem]").click(function(){
        console.log("Nothing to do here");  
    });

    $("#btnSaveOption").click(function(){
        // Some code for validations.
        // ...
        // and here is how I'm inserting a new row.
        var row = '<tr id="trItem-' + optionID + '">'+
                '<td id="tdIndex-' + optionID + '" width="10%">{{id}}</td>'+
                '<td id="optionTextFor_' + optionID + '" class="optionTextClass" width="60%">{{selectedText}}</td>'+
                '<td class="rigthOptionClass" width="20%">{{rightOption}}</td>'+
                '<td width="10%">{{actionButtons}}</td>' +
            '</tr>';

        table.append(row.compose({
                'id': optionID,
                'selectedText': selectedText,
                'rightOption': '<input id="chk_' + optionID + '" type="checkbox" name="chk[]" ' + 
                                (rightOption == "true" ? 'checked' : '') + ' disabled />',
                'actionButtons': '<span><i id="editItem-' + optionID + '-id-' + (optionID + 20) + 
                                '" class="fa fa-pencil-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; ' + 
                                '<i id="trashItem-' + optionID + '-id-' + (optionID + 20) + 
                                '" class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>' 
            }));
    });
});

I've already checked for any typo mistake but apparently everything is ok. If any one can see something wrong that I've must be missing or have a clue on what's happening please, little help will be appreciated! I'm stocking with this for a week now and I don't how what else to do.
Thanks in advance!
I've tried debbuging the HTML code, changing the listener for the element suppossed to handle the actions but nothing work so far.

You need to use event delegation concept. use .on('click' rather than .click(

You should consider event delegation rather than adding event listeners to individual elements

Also I see that you are using id for event handling. if id is repeatable then it will not work as id should be unique per element.

Thank you both, @Death-is-the-real-truth and @kmoser for you answers. I actually was aware of id's being repeatable so that's why I tried catching event with class, even I tried with $('.fa-trash-o').on('click', 'i', function(){ and nothing changed. I will keep looking but I have now a good hint to track on.

You can use like this:  $('#tableOptionList tbody').on('click','.fa-trash-o',function(){
